# loading JSON into WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, json, wpf

So this is my first time messing with WPF and i like it so far HOWEVER. I am saving and loading root names and child info all in JSON format which i have the class and all that working for.
I want to load the JSON nickname items into the listbox upon program load, which from the examples i see is supposed to be done with bindings and ItemsSources.

This is my XAML listbox code

```
<ListBox x:Name="nameListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding userNickname}" 
                              Margin="0,0,0,111" 
                              Foreground="Black" 
                              Background="#FF747474">                            
</ListBox>
```

This is my on load code

```
string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(userModule.jsonSettingsPath);
nameListBox.ItemsSource = jsonContent;
```

So it loads items by it loads every single letter/symbol in the file as it's own item. I've never tried to do this before so any help or insight as to what i should be doing or what is wrong that i don't see would be awesome.

This is just a project i'm fiddling around with trying to understand WPF, basically you save user info (nickname, full name, email, cell) into a JSON file/format and it loads on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it loads every single letter into it is because it iterates over your ItemSource. In your case it's a string, iterate over it and get every character.

What you need is to parse the Json first (into an object). I recommend using Newtonsoft.Json.

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonContent);
```

Comment: Ahh yeah okay now i get it i messed up so i had to tweak your code a little to make it work:
List<Users> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(jsonContent);
                nameListBox.ItemsSource = users.Select(x => x.Nickname);